# access to the files of bin folder on c# (convert .dll to .cs)

Tags: c#, dll, bin

I was working with my PC, and during developing my project the system had restarted, the problem is I had to lost my last code.

So is there any solution to use "last project" with "new bin-folder", my mean is can I combination those files with project ?

Thank you

Comment: Its very unusual for it not to save it before compliation

Comment: @hussy idea with decompiler with work but code will be as old as the one in your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably have a look at this decompiler and give it a shot:

http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/

Comment: Thank you, it returned some code with bug but I'm happy to see my code again :)